# How and Which tool should use to make API-Gateway for polyglot Microservice Platform?

Tags: nginx, load-balancing, microservices, haproxy, api-gateway

In the case of Microservice Architecture, there are a bunch of services built on different stack and communicate with each other and also the client via REST.

So what I'm asking for, to make that gateway a single entry point from a client or consumer `e.g api.domain.com` which will redirect the request to the corresponding service based on the endpoint as we know about purpose of api-gateway.

Well, It's possible by load-balancer like `nginx-plus` or `HAProxy` simply balancing load and passing proxy. But my expectations `(mostly about authentication-authorization based)` are below :

- The consumer will authenticate with credentials, server will return back small **access_token** `(minimal e.g user_id as payload)` which will store into client app. For further each request client will send this token as authorization how JWT or Token based authentication does.
- Before passing the request to another service `Gateway-service` will decode that small auth_token and will make another authorization token `(let's say Big Token)` with associated users all information (query by small token decoded payload) which will pass as Authorization to actual service and internal service to service call from where content will serve.
- That (Gateway-service generated) `Big-Token` and payload will store into `redis` for a while to reduce api call to get user information every time.
- Request caching and balancing load.

I'm not sure is it possible to achieve by `nginx-plus` or `HAproxy` probably **NO!** cause there we have few database query, api calling and caching into redis etc. Which is not possible by `nginx` or `HAProxy` or whatever like those.

I found two services for `Node.js/Express.js` for passing proxy [Node-HTTP-Proxy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-proxy) and [Express-Gateway](https://www.express-gateway.io/) which is only for expressjs api-services but here I'm using polyglot framework or languages.

> Note: Here services are built with python flask, Django and ExpressJS, few of them hosted into Unix VM where using nginx as load balancer and few of them hosted into azure app service where they use IIS as load balancer.

Thanks for reading and understanding, It would be great if you can suggest anyway or recommend anything.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you check out Ambasador - https://www.getambassador.io - it sounds like it would suit your needs. Another solid choice that has a lot of support and a large community is Kong - https://konghq.com. Other choices are [Nginx](https://www.nginx.com/blog/building-microservices-using-an-api-gateway/), [Loopback](https://loopback.io/) and [Tyk](https://github.com/TykTechnologies/tyk).

Comment: Thanks I’m checking will get back to you

Comment: I went through both seems doesn't meet my expectations thank you anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I am actually gonna recommend [Node-HTTP-Proxy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-proxy).

You could use a node server for `api.domain.com` that could use [Node-HTTP-Proxy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-proxy) . It can be used to consume micro services eg. `serviceone.com` and `servicetwo.com`. It will not care what you have used to build this micro services(eg. python flask, Django and ExpressJS) as long as you have them exposed as REST/SOAP api.

Say you have some endpoints like `serviceone.com/rone` and `servicetwo.com/rtwo`, 
You can make a request to `api.domain.com/rone` or `api.domain.com/rtwo` where you custom proxy server will use [Node-HTTP-Proxy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-proxy) and send request to `serviceone.com/rone` or `servicetwo.com/rtwo`. You can read headers from request and do something with it and change headers before sending request to micro services. Which would solve your authentication problem. You can use redis and caching here.

Worked nicely for me. Hope it helps.

Comment: It's the last option for me and I started that thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [Kong](https://konghq.com) for the use cases you have mentioned:

1. For the specific way of authentication you have mentioned, you will need to write a plugin using Lua. Kong has many authentication support built-in, but your requirement is a bit different.
2. Kong caches all of its data including consumers in-memory. So you don't need to implement another Redis based solution. When you have a new user, you will need to add that user as a consumer at Kong using its admin API.
3. Kong has load balancing support. And as it is built on top of Nginx, you can also configure the core Nginx if you need.
4. For request caching at the gateway level, Kong has a plugin for its enterprise edition. There are some open source community-built plugins as well.

Regarding the custom authentication, you should think twice why you need it at two levels. At the gateway level, you can authenticate and use ACL, the underlying services can trust the upcoming requests. You may need to implement service level middleware to identify the user that Kong is passing through, for resource level authorization.

**One caution**: *While working with Kong, I felt the necessity of proper thorough documentation.*

Comment: I'm trying exactly same steps but now studying with lua to write the plugin. BTW I want to use redis for storing token payload, not for request caching. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Kong caches consumers along with their tokens in-memory, you don't need redis here.

Comment: have access from other services also but well let me experiment will update you